# Epson SX235W scanner no longer detected via wifi

Tags: 14.04, wireless, printing, epson

I am on a Ubuntu 14.04 LTS machine, regularly updated.
I downloaded early this year the printer and scanner drivers for my Epson stylus SX235W from the [Epson download page](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule). The scanner driver is version 1.0.0 (iscan-bundle-1.0.0.x64.deb.tar.gz).
The device has a dedicated static ip in my router: 192.168.0.102
Once installed my all-in-one device worked fine via wifi until recently: the printer still works as before but the scanner is no longer recognised.
I used to use `simple scan` because the `image scan!` Epson Utility did not work (probably because uses as backend `epkowa` which was not configured properly.) 
Now even `simple scan` does not work any more:

```
Failed to scan
No scanners available. Please connect a scanner
```

The output of `scanimage -L` is:

```
asarluhi@SATELLITE-L50-A-161:~ $ scanimage -L

No scanners were identified.
```

I tried to install sane, which was not installed by default, but xsane too does not detect the scanner: `no devices available`.

**With the usb cable connected there are no relevant issues, so the problem I suppose is with the wireless network communication with the scanner**.
 With the usb cable, `scanimage -L` output is:

```
asarluhi@SATELLITE-L50-A-161:~ $ scanimage -L
device `epkowa:usb:003:003' is a Epson Stylus SX235W/NX230/TX230W Series flatbed scanner
```

The only issue is that, as I said before, being the `epkowa` backend not configured, only `simple scan` did its job. `Xscan` returned `failed to open device 'epkowa:usb:003:003': Device busy.`

I tried to edit file `etc/sane.d/epkowa.conf` adding the following line:

```
net 192.168.0.102
```

With this change, with wireless network communication, when I launch any scanner utility or `scanimage -L` the process requires more time to produce a response, but the result is still the same:

simple scan:

```
Failed to scan
Unable to start scan
```

xsane

```
no devices available
```

What would you suggest to do?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that firewall is not blocking the connection? I had similar issue which solved by changing ufw settings. It can be tested by:

```
root@joker:~# ufw status
Status: active
root@joker:~# ufw disable
Firewall stopped and disabled on system startup

joker@joker:~$ scanimage -L
device `epson2:net:AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD' is a Epson PID 0885 flatbed scanner
```